# Error install jsf 2.2 in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to create my first JSF web dynamic project with eclipse. In second last step, I need to select the user library in which the download library window I got an error: [Unhandled event loop exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXsnH.png)

Comment: Would you mind telling us a bit more context. What I read from the provided error summary, you have GTK3 on the system and something states not being proted to that version (yet). Did you clikc on the Details>> button and what did it show? the steps before "second last step" might also help people expereinced with this to spot an error you might have made early on in the process, but that only surfaces at ythe step where you encounted it.

Comment: can you please share event logs ?